# How to "call" a keymap

Tags: keymap

I would like to have a function `call-keymap` which takes one argument `km` (a keymap) and such that the result of `(call-keymap km)` is the same as binding `km` to a key and then pressing that key.

It should look something like this

```
(defun call-keymap (km)
    (while (keymapp km)
      (setq km (lookup-key km (read-key-sequence ""))))
   (call-interactively km))
```

except that this doesn't work (specifically the last line is wrong, since a non-keymap entry of a keymap needn't be a function).

Intuitively, it would seem that the main command loop in emacs should be something like

```
(while t
  (call-keymap (current-global-map))
```

(or rather, it should do something with `current-active-maps` instead of `current-global-map`).

I was surprised to not be able to find a built-in function with the desired functionality of `call-keymap`, since this seems to me to be such a basic function.

Could someone please point me to such a built-in, or indicate how to fix the above definition?

---

**Edit 2019-01-23**

Stefan very rightly asked that I explain what my use-case is for such a function.

I use `evil-mode` and have `SPC` as a prefix-key for various useful commands when in `normal-state`. In `insert-state`, I would like some other binding (say, `M-SPC`) to produce the same behaviour as `SPC` in normal mode (I think emacs-DOOM has such a feature). My idea was then to bind `M-SPC` to a function which fetches the current `normal-state` binding of `SPC` (which is a keymap) and calls it.

Presumably, there are other good solutions to this, so that my original question may be moot, though I would be still be interested to know the answer. For example, here is one quite-hacky-but-maybe-not-entirely-unsatisfactory solution to my problem:

```
(defun set-alt-space ()
    (evil-local-set-key 'insert (kbd "M-SPC") (key-binding (kbd "SPC"))))
(add-hook 'evil-normal-state-exit-hook 'set-alt-space)
```

Comment: Can you give us some example use-case for such a function?

Comment: I think spacemacs does something like what you ask for in the edit. Maybe it is done in a simple way you can copy? The naive solution is to bind both normal mode SPC and insert mode M-SPC to the same key map but this doesn’t work with mode maps in the mix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your keymap is a menu, you can use `popup-menu`.

If it's not a menu but is just a normal keymap for normal keys (e.g. typically bound to a prefix key), then I don't think there's a predefined function for that.  But in your example `call-keymap` function, if you replace `call-interactively` with `execute-command`, should cover the majority of cases.  Of course, it still won't reproduce the normal way commands are executed because it fails to set `this-command`, `last-command`, run `pre/post-command-hook`, handle the `prefix-arg`, move cursor out of invisible text, etc...

To faithfully reproduce the way the command loop runs commands, the only good way is to ... use the command loop.  One way is with `recursive-edit`, but that covers a *sequence* of commands rather than just one (and it needs to be exited "manually").

In your case, I think the better answer is `set-transient-map`.  E.g. your `M-SPC` command could look something like:

```
(defun my-one-time-normal-SPC ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((map (lookup-key evil-normal-state-map "\s")))
    (set-transient-map map)))
```

Comment: Yes, I had tried that as well (or rather, with `command-execute`), but it still fails, for example, when `self-insert-command` is in the keymap -- and in any case, I am still left with the feeling that there should be a very canonical way to do this...

Comment: @JojHelfer: OK, I added info to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! `set-transient-map` is just the thing! And it is indeed mentioned in the elisp docs; I had just missed it.